# Rust disable struct construction

Tags: struct, rust, constructor, pattern-matching

How can I disable struct construction but maintaining pattern matching in Rust?

Let's see an example:

```rust
struct OrderedPair(pub u32, pub u32);

impl OrderedPair {
    fn new(a: u32, b: u32) -> Self {
        if a < b {
            Self(a, b)
        } else {
            Self(b, a)
        }
    }
}
```

It's obvious that I want to inhibit the construction of such struct (e.g. `OrderedPair(2, 1)`) and to use only the `new` method, in order to preserve the invariant. I know of 3 ways to do this:

1. Make private the fields

```rust
struct OrderedPair(u32, u32);
```

2. Add a private dummy field

```rust
struct OrderedPair(pub u32, pub u32, ());
```

3. Make the struct non-exhaustive

```rust
#[non_exhaustive]
struct OrderedPair(pub u32, pub u32);
```

The issues are that with 1 I cannot access the members at all and with all three I cannot use pattern matching

```rust
let OrderedPair(min, max) = my_ordered_pair;
```

So is there a way to block struct construction but allow pattern matching?

I know that if we declare a mutable variable of that type with public access to members then the invariant can be broken by manually changing the members, but for now avoiding the struct constructor is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing pattern matching directly on the fields, you can do it on a returned tupple:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct OrderedPair {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}
impl OrderedPair {
    pub fn new(a: u32, b: u32) -> Self {
        let (a, b) = if a < b { (a, b) } else { (b, a) };
        Self { a, b }
    }
    pub fn content(self) -> (u32, u32) {
        (self.a, self.b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of it. It could be a really great compromise.

Comment: Would it help if you implement the Deref (to pair) trait?

Comment: @hkBst No. Don't. From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html): *"Deref should only be implemented for smart pointers to avoid confusion"*. And it's a very sound advice.

Comment: That makes me consider whether this is a smart pointer ;p... On a more serious note: do you have some pointers how this could be confusing?

Comment: @hkBst Don't you think it will be a little unclear when you use *x in the middle of an iterator chain and you don't get your OrderedPair but a tuple ? And what happens when there's more, or you need to apply functions but you don't have the OrderedPair but a tuple ?