# Allow pattern destructuring but disallow construction

Tags: rust, design-patterns, pattern-matching

Suppose I have the following `src/lib.rs`

```
pub enum Toppings {
    Almond,
    Caramel,
    Cookie,
    Marshmallow,
    ChocolateSprinkles,
}
pub enum Icecream {
    Chocolate(Toppings),
    Mint(Toppings),
    Vanilla(Toppings),
}
```

I want to allow pattern destructure s.t. people can use the library like any other enum with associated data:

```
use Icecream::*;
use Toppings::*;

fn order_how_many(icecream: Icecream) -> usize {
    match icecream {
        Chocolate(Marshmallow) => 42,
        Vanilla(Cookie) => 69,
        _ => 42069,
    }
}
```

But at the same time I want to forbid creation of certain combinations of enum and its associated data, e.g. maybe the local ice cream store thinks double chocolate is too much and would never sell `Icecream::Chocolate(Toppings::ChocolateSprinkles)`, so we should outright forbid any possibility this combination is constructed. I find this hard to implement in Rust, since I need `pub enum` to allow pattern destruction, but making the `enum` public means all of its variants are `pub`.

I tried private token similar to which sometimes could be found in [sealed trait pattern](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/hidden-trait-implementation/41436), using private modules and prevents any accidental `pub use` via `#[forbid(missing_docs)]`, s.t. only crate implementation can decide what `Icecream`/`Toppings` combination are possible, but this makes pattern matching ugly (require `_` or `..` in every pattern destruction).

```
mod icecream {
    // Intentionally NOT use /// comment for this mod
    // to prevent accidental `pub use`
    #[forbid(missing_docs)]
    mod hide {
        pub struct Hide;
    }
    pub enum Toppings {
        Almond,
        Caramel,
        Cookie,
        Marshmallow,
        ChocolateSprinkles,
    }
    pub enum Icecream {
        Chocolate(Toppings, hide::Hide),
        Mint(Toppings, hide::Hide),
        Vanilla(Toppings, hide::Hide),
    }
    pub use Icecream::*;
    pub use Toppings::*;
}

pub use icecream::*;
fn order_how_many(icecream: Icecream) -> usize { // OK
    match icecream {
        Chocolate(Marshmallow, _) => 42,
        Vanilla(Cookie, ..) => 69,
        _ => 42069,
    }
}
fn str_to_icecream(base: &str, topping: &str) -> Option<Icecream> { // Compile fail as intended
    if base.to_lowercase() == "chocollate" && topping.to_lowercase() == "chocolatesprinkles" {
        Some(Chocolate(ChocolateSprinkles, icecream::hide::Hide))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Before posting the question SO suggested me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313934/rust-disable-struct-construction), but it also doesn't seem to fix the problem of `enum` here, since `enum` unlike `struct` cannot have different visibility between the type itself and its associated members, and that this would make having different shape of associated data more cumbersome to implement, e.g. if the length of tuples are different I'd probably have to implement a trait and return trait objects if I were to use this method.

Is there a more elegant/natural/rustacean way to do this? Or one should outright try avoid such code at the beginning, maybe since it's deemed as a bad practice?

Comment: Instead of specifying `Chocolate(Toppings)`, you could create a new type `ChocolateToppings`, make this one unconstructible and then do `Chocolate(ChocolateToppings)`. You can then controll in `ChocolateToppings` which topping it can accept. Having a different type for every enum entry is a pretty common thing, for example in [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.87/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't allow pattern-matching on `enum`s without also allowing them to be constructed.

However, `struct` fields can be private, which lets you do things like this:

```
pub enum Toppings {
    Almond,
    Caramel,
    Cookie,
    Marshmallow,
    ChocolateSprinkles,
}

pub enum Flavour {
    Chocolate,
    Mint,
    Vanilla,
}

pub struct Icecream {
    pub flavour: Flavour,
    pub toppings: Toppings,
    _secret: (), // non-pub, prevents construction from outside the module
}
```

You can no longer construct `Icecream` except from functions in the same module; these are the only things allowed to access the `_secret` field. Code outside of the module may still destructure the values, but must use `..` to avoid naming the `_secret` field.

You'd rewrite your other functions like this:

```
// this can be in any module
fn order_how_many(icecream: Icecream) -> usize { // OK
    match icecream {
        Icecream { flavour: Chocolate, .. } => 42,
        Icecream { flavour: Vanilla, toppings: Cookie, .. } => 69,
        _ => 42069,
    }
}

// this must be in the same module as the `Icecream` struct
fn str_to_icecream(base: &str, topping: &str) -> Option<Icecream> {
    if base.to_lowercase() == "chocolate" && topping.to_lowercase() == "chocolatesprinkles" {
        Some(
            Icecream { 
                flavour: Chocolate,
                toppings: ChocolateSprinkles,
                _secret: () 
            }
        )
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that. You are of course right. There is no point in having `topping` be part of the enum if every enum option carries it. Just move both in a struct.

Comment: Using struct seems do help here, at least I don't have to specify private modules and could just utilize visibility of members of struct instead.

Besides I can do this, allowing different amount of associated data:
`pub enum Grade {Eco(Toppings), Recommended(Toppings, Toppings), Luxury(Toppings, Toppings, Toppings),}` and then `pub struct Icecream {pub flavour: Flavour, pub toppings: Grade, _secret: (),}`